# Binary Maze Generator

Tags: algorithm, binary, maze

[image]I'm trying to make a simple maze generator using the simplest algorithm I know of.
This is what my code looks like right now but there is almost never a path from start to finish and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the algorithm [page](https://hurna.io/academy/algorithms/maze_generator/binary.html)

```
function generateMaze() {
  let cells = []

  for (var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
    let cell = new Cell(nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y)

    cells.push(cell)
    //obstacles.push([nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y])


  }


  
  for (var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
    if (round(random(1, 2)) == 1){
      obstacles.push([cells[i].x, cells[i].y-base])
    }
    else{
      obstacles.push([cells[i].x-base, cells[i].y])
    }
  }
}


}


class Cell{
  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.has_visited = false
    this.neigbors = []
  }
}
```

Obstacles is just an empty array to hold the walls and base is how big each block is.

Comment: I think you have reversed the logic for free and obstacles, the algorithm states that you punch through obstacles, but here it looks like your generating obstacles.

Comment: I've tried both but the result looks the same either way

Comment: how is nodes initialized?

Comment: @Surt actually there isn't much difference. If implemented correctly either way would create a binary-tree based maze. They'd just be different.

Comment: There's multiple quite a bit of code missing here. E.g. where are the variables `nodes` and `base` declared? Could you please add those? See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for details

Comment: so nodes is just a grid of x and y coordinates that I used to make cells